# VBA arrays: Find minimum of range, offset value and output value in MsgBox

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to understand arrays, but just cant fully wrap the my head around the concept. I have the following data set:

[image]

And I wrote the following code to confirm that the value in Column B is greater than zero, if so it feeds the value into the array and then outputs the minimum value in a message box:

```
Sub MinFunc()

Dim ValLng(1 To 5) As Long, x As Long

x = 3

For i = 1 To 5
    If Cells(x, 2).Value > 0 Then
        ValLng(i) = Cells(x, 1).Value
        Cells(x, 2).Value = Cells(x, 2).Value - 1
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next i

MsgBox (Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ValLng))

End Sub
```

Now I have two issues with the code:

1. I need the upper end of the array to be variable, because when the macro is run often enough at some point the upper end of the array will be 4, then 3 and so on.
2. Rather than outputting the minimum value itself, I would like to output the value in Column C associated with the minimum. I tried to offset the value in the message box, but was not successful.

Can you please give me direction in how I can achieve points 1 and 2?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Array is data structure which has defined size at the beginning. If you need bigger array then new one needs to be created because new memory needs to be alocated. In VBA the `Redim` statement can be used to achieve this. For the second question have a look at `Range.Offset` property.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help dee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to have an array with a dynamic size.

First, define the array without defining a constant size, use `Dim ValLng() As Variant`.

Second, `Redim` it to a large size at the begining , use `ReDim ValLng(0 To 1000)`.

Third, after you finished populating the array with all matches inside your `For` loop, optimize the array by resizing it, use `ReDim Preserve ValLng(0 To x - 1)`. `Redim Preserve` means you are `Redim`ing the array, but keeping the values inside it.

The code below will get you started:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MinFunc()

Dim ValLng() As Variant, x As Long, i As Long
Dim MinRes, RngFind As Range

ReDim ValLng(0 To 1000) '<-- init dynamic array size to a very large value , will optimize later
x = 3

'-- just for example, loop until the last cell with data in Column B
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(x, 2).Value > 0 Then
        ValLng(i) = Cells(x, 1).Value
        Cells(x, 2).Value = Cells(x, 2).Value - 1
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next i

ReDim Preserve ValLng(0 To x - 1) '<-- resize array to actual size found
MinRes = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ValLng)

Set RngFind = Cells.Find(What:=MinRes, After:=Range("A1"), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) '<-- use find method
Cells(RngFind.Row, 3) = MinRes '<-- put the Minimum value at column C at the same row

End Sub
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for putting me on track Shai!

Comment: In regards to Set RngFind = Cells.Find(What:=MinRes, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole): How can I exclude values from the seach that have a 0 value in column B?

Comment: You right, got it. Sorry I changed the code to something incorrect. Thanks again.